# How to do a web.config transform for smtp?

Tags: web-config, smtp, xdt-transform

I have this in my root web.config

```
 <mailSettings>
     <smtp from="no-reply@test.com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
         <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\temp"/>
         <network host="localhost"/>
     </smtp>
 </mailSettings>
```

Of course when I put this to my hosting server I don't want it to be saving to the harddrive I want it to send out the emails.

So I would have something like this

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
      <network host="smtp.mysite.com" userName="myuser" password="mypassword" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

How could I put this in my web.release.config? Should I just do a replace of the mailSettings. I am not sure really how to the transforms yet.

Answer (score 66):

Add `xdt:Transform="Replace"` to your .release

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <network host="smtp.mysite.com" userName="myuser" password="mypassword" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Octopus deploy is not able to run this transform. it only does for appSettings and connectionStrings. Do you know if this works for Octopus deploy?

Comment: Octopus deploy is now able to perform this transformation, just tested it

Answer (score 2):

You could use web.config transformation in asp.net 4

you would write a transformation rule to match a local rule to be replaced when you are publishing your website in a specific transformation

there is some great information on this here

http://blog.hmobius.com/post/2010/02/17/ASPNET-40-Part-4-Config-Transformation-Files.aspx ([Archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20110512194521/http://blog.hmobius.com/post/2010/02/17/ASPNET-40-Part-4-Config-Transformation-Files.aspx))

Comment: sorry yes I am aware of transformation I was wondering how to do it. I will look into that article.

Comment: @chobo2 the article does contain how to do it, so kindly accept @stack72 asnwer

Comment: The linked page does have the answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: aaaand the link is now dead. As predicted.